# Do two sinusoidals with different amplitude and phase always intersect at two places in a time period?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Consider two trajectories:
$$x_1(t)=A \sin t+B\cos t$$

$$x_2(t)=C \sin t+D\cos t$$

I was trying to find how many times the trajectories of two particles that evolve with the above-given equations cross each other in a time interval.

On plotting the functions for various values of $(A, B, C, D)$ I found that in a period of $2\pi$ the functions intersected at exactly two values.

Is there a theorem that says that there always are exactly two simultaneous solutions of two sinusoidals with different amplitudes and phases in a period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Harmonic addition theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicAdditionTheorem.html) on $x_1(t)-x_2(t)=(A-C)\sin t+(B-D)\cos t$ to represent $x_1(t)-x_2(t)$ as $R\cos(t-\phi)$, where $R=\sqrt{(A-C)^2+(B-D)^2}$ and $\phi$ is some phase angle.

Now, unless $A=C$ and $B=D$ (in which case $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ coincide), we will have $R\ne 0$. In that case, $x_1(t)-x_2(t)=R\cos(t-\phi)$ is just another cosine curve with the same period $2\pi$, and, as such, has exactly two zeros at any interval of size $2\pi$. Those zeros are the points of intersection of $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$.